# How do you display a png image in string format in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, png

I have a function in Ruby that returns the data for a QR Code image in PNG format that works as follows:

```
puts generate_qr_code("this is a test")

�PNG

IHDk�XTPLTE,�)�[��tRNS@��f�IDATx���Kr��M�ѭ8)
                                                �<��q����(�x��H�$I�$I�$I�$I�$�+����
```

*What would be the simplest way to take this string and display in a Rails view?*

I have a couple of ideas on how this could be possilbe such as saving the data in a `@img_data` variable and the view some how displaying it. Or perhaps saving into a file and passing it's url. The images generated will only be used temporarily so saving the data somewhere wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Are you having an issue displaying characters in your question?

Comment: That was just an example to show that the function returns the data for the image. Being image data, when printed to the screen � is expected. I'm not sure how to use this data in a rails image_tag for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  def render_qr_code                                                               
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = "public"                                                    
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/png"                                 
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = "inline"                                              
    render :body => generate_qr_code("this is a test")                                                                 
  end
```

Then in you view you do `<img src="controller_name/render_qr_code">`. You need a route etc...

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> What would be the simplest way to take this string and display in a Rails view?

Construct a [data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) using the Base64-encoded image data and pass it to the [`image_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag) helper:

```
# controller
def show
  @image_data = generate_qr_code('this is a test')
end

# view
<%= image_tag "data:image/png;base64,#{Base64.strict_encode64(@image_data)}" %>
```

You could also wrap this in a helper method:

```
# helper
def qr_image_tag(text, options = {})
  image_data = generate_qr_code(text)
  data_uri   = "data:image/png;base64,#{Base64.strict_encode64(image_data)}"
  image_tag(data_uri, options)
end

# view
<%= qr_image_tag('this is a test') %>
```